# C# TCP Chat-Server: Connection only works one way

Tags: c#, tcp, connection

I've got a **generic TCP Client and TCP Listener** setup on my main laptop and my other laptop. The client and listener are their own **separate programs**, so I've had a client and server running on both laptops to try and get a **simple instant messenger** going.

1. The client and server will **happily communicate** with each other if both programs are executed on the **same laptop**. This is true for both my main and other laptop.
2. My **main laptop**'s client will **happily send messages to my other laptop**, and the **other laptop will gracefully receive messages from my main** laptop.
3. **However**, when my other laptop's client sends a message to my main laptop's server it gets a **timeout-related, communication-failed type of error**. It just doesn't send the message.

**Error message (caught by try-catch);** "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond {my IP:port number}."

I'm getting the IP and port numbers correct, so rule that out.
There's no firewall business because the other laptop doesn't care at all about receiving messages from my main laptop.

I've also **tried random port numbers** and made sure that the client on my main laptop is connecting over the same port number that my other laptop's sever is listening on (or accepting messages from).

So why isn't my other laptop successfully sending messages to my main laptop?

The client asks for the user to enter an IP and then a port number. It then waits for the user to enter a message, then connects and sends that message to the IP via the given port number.

The server asks the user to enter a port number and prints messages received through that port.

Here's the code for the client program;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string IP = localIPAddress();
        Console.WriteLine("Your IP: " + IP); //provides IP number
        Console.Write("Enter IP to connect to: ");
        string connectToIP = Console.ReadLine();
        if (connectToIP == "self")
        {
            connectToIP = localIPAddress(); 
            // if I want to test both on the same computer
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter port number: ");
        int portNo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (true)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                // connection doesn't begin until ReadLine is done
                request(connectToIP, portNo, message); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string localIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }

    static void request(string address, int port, string message)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        client.SendTimeout = 1000;
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

        try
        {
            client.Connect(address, port);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            sw.WriteLine(message);

            sw.Flush();

            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(a.Message.ToString());
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for the server;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your IP: " + localIPAddress());
        Console.Write("Enter port number you're receiving from: ");
        int portNo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portNo);
        Socket connection;
        NetworkStream socketStream;
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
            connection.SendTimeout = 1000;
            connection.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            socketStream = new NetworkStream(connection);
            try
            {
                respond(socketStream);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                socketStream.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string localIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }

    static void respond(NetworkStream strm)
    {
        List<string> sentIn = new List<string>();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);

        while (sr.Peek() != -1)
            sentIn.Add(sr.ReadLine());

        sr.Close();

        foreach (string s in sentIn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Is there a problem with my code? There have been no Firewall-related messages when either laptop uses these programs.

It might be the sw.Flush() for the client, because that used to cause the sending process to freeze.

Thanks in advance. Once I get this problem sorted, I can start wondering how this can be used to make a multiplayer XNA game.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try making the timeouts a little longer (or remove them all together; they caused problems for me). Also, it's really a good idea to create a thread to receive messages while you handle the sending on the main thread.

Some notes:

You can use "loopback" or "127.0.0.1" if you'd like to connect to your local IP

```
if (connectToIP == "self")
{
    connectToIP = localIPAddress(); 
    // if I want to test both on the same computer
}
```

You really shouldn't connect, send a single message, and then disconnect, only to connect again.

Try something like this for the client:

```
using System.Threading;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        Console.Write("IP: ");
        string ip = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Port: ");
        int port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        try
        {
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            Thread readThread = new Thread(() => readSocket(sr));
            readThread.Start(); //Run readSocket() at the same time
            string message = "";
            while (message != "exit")
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(message);
            }
            client.Close();
            return;                
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
    }

    static void readSocket(StreamReader sr)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = "";
            while ((message = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException) { /*when we force close, this goes off, so ignore it*/ }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of the Server:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Port: ");
        int port = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        try
        {
            server.Start();
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            Thread readThread = new Thread(() => readSocket(sr));
            readThread.Start();
            string message = "";
            while (message != "exit")
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(message);
            }
            client.Close();
            return;                
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
    }

    static void readSocket(StreamReader sr)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = "";
            while ((message = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException) { /*when we force close, this goes off, so ignore it*/ }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[image: Final Client and Server]

Here is the code for an Async server that forwards messages to all connected clients (If you were worried about not being able to share a port).

I'm trying to keep these examples simple, but it's probably a good idea to add more exception handling to all of them.

```
class Server
{
    private int port;
    private Socket serverSocket;
    private List<StateObject> clientList;
    private const int DEFAULT_PORT = 1338;

    public Server()
    {
        this.port = 1338; //default port
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientList = new List<StateObject>();
    }

    public Server(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientList = new List<StateObject>();
    }

    public void startListening(int port = DEFAULT_PORT)
    {
        this.port = port;
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.port));
        serverSocket.Listen(1);
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            //Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            clientList.Add(state);
            state.workSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)AR.AsyncState;
        Socket s = state.workSocket;
        try
        {
            int received = s.EndReceive(AR);

            if (received == 0)
                return;

            if (received > 0)
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));

            string content = state.sb.ToString();

            if (content.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > -1)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(content);
                foreach (StateObject others in clientList)
                    if (others != state)
                        others.workSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content.ToCharArray()));
                state.sb.Clear();
            }

            Array.Clear(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize);
            s.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception huh) {
            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
            //Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
            clientList.Remove(state);
            return;
        }
    }
    class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: 3rd EDIT: Okay it's working now, but they have to be using different ports. I've tried threading before to no avail, but your code works so long as the laptops' own client and the server it connects to don't share a port number.

Comment: Okay there's a chance that the other laptop's client will close for no reason, and it will also fail to send messages. This seems more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're having trouble with exactly. You can only have one server running on one port, and in this setup it can only handle one connection. If you're trying to keep them connected for long periods of time, you can add some code to reconnect when it encounters an exception. I'll add an example of an async server if you're interested in that, but I tried to keep this example as simple as possible. If you want to catch errors and have it reconnect, you can add that in. It should be a matter of catching exception, disconnect (client and server) and reconnect.

Comment: Also, don't forget that I basically ignore the system.io exception on both of them. This is probably one of the most common exceptions to go off, so if it's stopping "for no reason" it's probably because the reading/writing errored and the exception was ignored. You can change this line to show you the exception: catch (System.IO.IOException) { /*when we force close, this goes off, so ignore it*/ }